Create watermark in react-leaflet
The error Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'Control') is thrown, where do I find the necessary imports? I've tried the answers from this post as well as the official documentation but I have to use react-leaflet as the core leaflet has issues with SSR.
import { MapContainer, Marker, Popup, TileLayer } from 'react-leaflet'
import L from 'react-leaflet'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility'
import 'leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility/dist/leaflet-defaulticon-compatibility.webpack.css'
import 'leaflet/dist/leaflet.css'

const Map = (props) => {

    const Custom = () => {       

        L.Control.Watermark = L.Control.extend({
            onAdd: function (map) {
                var img = L.DomUtil.create('img');
    
                img.src = 'https://leafletjs.com/docs/images/logo.png';
                img.style.width = '200px';
    
                return img;
            },
    
            onRemove: function (map) {
                // Nothing to do here
            }
        });
    
        const loadMap = L.control.watermark = function (opts) {
            return new L.Control.Watermark(opts);
        }

        return loadMap
    }
    

    return (
        <MapContainer center={[51.505, -0.09]} zoom={13} scrollWheelZoom={false} style={{ height: 400, width: "100%", borderRadius: '1em' }}>
            <TileLayer
                attribution='&copy; <a href="http://osm.org/copyright">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors'
                url="https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
            />
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.09]}>
                <Popup>
                    {props.stuff.jack}
                </Popup>
            </Marker>
            <Marker position={[51.505, -0.11]}></Marker>     
            {Custom()}              
        </MapContainer>
    )
}

export default Map

